# Apache Reverse Proxy for user customized http iFrames

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2, reverse-proxy

I have a web application where users can specify a custom website that they host to be displayed in an iFrame on the page.

The problem is, my web app runs in HTTPS where as user's webpages in the iFrames do not have SSL enabled and are in http. This causes their webpage to be blocked from showing for a mixed content security warning.

My idea, was to setup a reverse proxy on my Apache webserver. This reverse proxy would take something like https://example.com/reverse?theirsite=http://example.com

**This reverse proxy would need to work for websocket connections as well:**
wss:// -> ws://
and
https:// -> http://

Is this the best way to go about displaying a user's insecure webpage in an iFrame on my web app?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # Reverse proxy for iFrames
        # https -> http and wss -> ws
        # get the SITE querystring for the IP/Port
        ProxyPass /proxy {site}
        ProxyPassReverse /proxy {site}
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache would need to take a custom query string and forward it to the insecure site.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the best way?

If you want to provide a way for everyone on the internet to surf for porn anonymously, attack other websites and generally do bad things, then you're spot on. Unfortunately it won't do what you intend.

First, you're going to need some application logic to implement this is - e.g. PHP, Python, Perl, Java....

Then you'll need a way to store mappings between URLs on your site and those of your users.

Then you write some code which listens at the iframe URL to translate a request using the map. When it receives a response from the origin site, it will hen need to re-write any URLs therein to something which will be routed back to your server.

Once you've done all this, you will have something which looks like it works, however anyone with a user account now has the ability to attack your sites security via XSS. So really you need a dedicated vhost within your domain such that each user's content runs within its own origin.

This is not trivial.